# gRPC Unary Stream from Python server -> C# Client: "Stream removed"

Tags: python, grpc

I have a unary streaming service from a Python server (1.8.4) to C# client (1.8.3).

When I signal the Python to shutdown (TERM15) the `shutdown` method in the code listing below is called, the intention of which is to terminate the RPCs gracefully, and shut the server down.

This works when I'm running a server on localhost, an RpcException with the expected status is raised: `Status(StatusCode=Cancelled, Detail="Completed")`

However, when running the server in Kubernetes(GKE) and terminating the pod I receive: `Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unknown, Detail="Stream removed")` in the client.  The python server is behind an haproxy ingress controller and google-cloud-endpoint proxy, but in my understanding neither of these components should affect the connection.

Can anybody think what could be causing the different statuses in the RpcException on the client?

```py
class StreamsService(StreamsServicer):
    def MyHandler(self, request, context):
        while not stop_event.isSet():
            try:
                yield update_q.get(True, 0.1)
            except queue.Empty:
                continue

        context.set_code(grpc.StatusCode.CANCELLED)
        context.set_details("Completed")

def shutdown(subscriber_service: StreamsService,
             executor: futures.ThreadPoolExecutor,
             server: grpc.Server, exit_code):    

    logger.info("Stopping stream handlers")
    for stop_event in subscriber_service.stop_events:
        stop_event.set()

    logger.info("Stopping executor")
    executor.shutdown()

    logger.info("Stopping server")
    ev: threading.Event = server.stop(grace=10)  # allows RPCs to terminate gracefully

    logger.info("Waiting for server to stop gracefully")
    ev.wait()

    logger.info("Stopping process with exit code {}".format(exit_code))
    sys.exit(exit_code)
```

(ps. cross-posted from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/Ge6hcUUhXzo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this *was* a problem with the google-cloud-endpoint/NGINX container being terminated before the gRPC server container in the same pod had a chance to close it's connections gracefully.

If anyone is remotely interested in knowing more, there's a conversation I had with myself over here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/FyfdvD6xS1Q